# SharePoint 2010 - setting peoplepicker-searchadforests, unable to remove property and get <Property Exist="No"> after setting with no -url param

Tags: 2010, powershell, people-picker, stsadm

Interesting behavior that I was hoping someone could help with.

Trying to adjust the "**peoplepicker-searchadforests**" property using the stsadm command in Powershell, I ran the below command:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:2NDDOMAIN"
```

No -url param was sent in

It properly set and now I get the following when running getproperty:

```
stsadm -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests
<Property Exist="Yes" Value="domain:2NDDOMAIN" />
```

If I attempt to clear it, this is where things fall apart:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv ""
or
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv
```

results with a getproperty output of:

```
<Property Exist="Yes" Value="" />
```

I'm unable to get Exist to equal "No".

If I run the above commands, but send in a -url value, this problem doesn't happen and I'm able to successfully remove the property.

**Example:**

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:2NDDOMAIN" -url http://our.sharepointsite.com
```

results in:

```
<Property Exist="Yes" Value="domain:2NDDOMAIN" />
```

and if I do:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "" -url http://our.sharepointsite.com
```

I get:

```
<Property Exist="No" />
```

However, with this initial one, I can't find a way to get the Exist value to be "No".  Trying to use

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "" -url
or
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "" -url ""
```

only results in an error because it's not a valid/properly formed URL.

Is there a registry value, web.config file, or anything I could manually edit to remove/delete this property so that I get ?

The worst part is that doing this seemed to solve the problem I ran the command for in the first place (have People Picker in SP2010 search the current and a second domain we have).  But I can't do the same on our production server if I'm not able to undo it if the same doesn't happen there.